# Construct a branch $f(z)$ of $\log z$ such that $f(z)$ is analytic at $z=-1$ and takes on the value $5\pi i$ there.

Tags: complex-analysis

Construct a branch $f(z)$ of $\log z$ such that $f(z)$ is analytic at $z=-1$ and takes on the value $5\pi i$ there.

I'm not really sure what I need to do to find this branch. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: If any of the answeres below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to find an argument $\arg{z}$ such that $$\log(-1) = \log|-1|+i\arg{(-1)} = 5\pi i.$$ That means you want $$\arg(-1) = 5\pi.$$ For exemple you can put the cut's branch on $[0,+\infty[$ and define your argument to be in $[4\pi,6\pi[.$